# How does automatic passing the arguments to function as an argument work in JS?

Tags: javascript, callback

What is the logic inside of it? How can we understand that `"Hello world"` is the `s` argument in `function b(s)`? How can we pass it inside of that function? How do these 2 arguments (simple value and function with argument) cooperate with each other? Seems like there is no connection between them but it works properly.

P.S. The second example is pretty clear.

```
//1st example

a("Hello world", b);

function b(s) {
    console.log(s + "!!!");
}

//2nd example

a("Hello world", function(s) {
    console.log(s + ", how are you?");
});

function a(s, callback) {
    callback(s);
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Your question doesn't involve a direct coding issue. Instead you're asking us to explain working code. SO is not the place to ask such questions. Perhaps [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be more suitable? Though I'm not entirely sure about that either.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to be more accurate next time.

Comment: It isnt automatic? You do callback(s) ...

Comment: I wonder about passing arguments[0] into arguments of function which is represented as arguments[1]. Why does it happen? Does JS automatically simply pass it? And again, 2nd example is clear to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a("Hello world", b);

function a(s, callback) {
  callback(s);
  // s -> "Hello World"
  // callback -> b
  // callback(s) -> b("Hello World")

}

// so.. b("Hello World")
function b(s) {
  // s -> "Hello World"
  console.log(s + "!!!");
  // result: "Hello World!!!"
}
```

Update.
[image]

Comment: The thing I cannot get is  `// s -> "Hello World"` for `function b(s)`. How and why?

Comment: look inside function a, there's `callback(s)`, replace `callback` with `b`, and you have `b(s)`, `s` is `"Hello World"`, so `b(s)` -> `b("Hello World")`.